# SQL Server logins and Active Directory (AD) logins/authentication in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, authentication

Looking for technical info regarding SQL Server logins and Windows/Active Directory (AD) logins/authentication in SQL Server 2012.

If I use this to create an AD login:

```
CREATE LOGIN [BLAH\joe] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master] ;
```

then the security identifier (SID) that is stored with the login in SQL Server is one that is retrieved from the AD server in the BLAH domain. Correct?

**SQL Server Logins**: I can also do this:

```
exec sp_help_revlogin
```

which returns something like (shortened and changed for brevity/security):

```
CREATE LOGIN [joe] 
WITH PASSWORD = 0x020053764hff, 
     SID = x0F6A61bgyu6474hff, 
     DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], 
     CHECK_POLICY = OFF, 
     CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
```

So for SQL Server logins only (not AD logins) I can specify a SID with `CREATE LOGIN` (or let SQL Server create a SID for me).

Is there any link between that SID and AD?

Why would I need to specify the SID for a SQL Server login? Is it in case I backup a db on one server, then restore it in another server, and want to avoid orphaned SQL Server logins?

Does this utility:

```
exec sp_change_users_login 'update_one','<user>','<user>'
```

change the user SID in the just-restored db to match the login SID?

**AD Logins**: as for AD logins, lets say I backup a db in domain A, then restore it in domain B. Is any given AD login that is in both domains, but with different SIDs, going to be unable to immediately connect to the db in the B domain?

Or to be more succinct: if I want to backup a db in domain A, then restore it in domain B, do the AD logins that connect to the database have to have the same AD SIDs in both domains for things to just work?  If they don't, can I somehow get past that in SQL Server?

Also: with an AD login in SQL Server, does SQL Server communicate with the AD server every time it tries to authenticate?

Thanks for any help
aj

Comment: Hi, Can you solve your problem, please? I would also like to connect to an AD from an SQL server but it always throws an error.